# Post multipart via ktor-client

Tags: kotlin, multipartform-data, ktor

I have to make a multipart request via ktor-client. Request method:

```
    suspend fun uploadPhoto(userId: String, bitmapPhoto: BitmapPhoto) {
        kotlin.runCatching {
            val response: HttpResponse = httpClient.submitFormWithBinaryData(
                url = BASE_URL.plus("$userId/${bitmapPhoto.name}"),
                formData = formData {
                    append("file", bitmapPhoto.bitmap.toByteArray(),
                        Headers.build {
                            append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary")
                            append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "form-data; name=file; filename=${bitmapPhoto.name}")
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
}
```

When executing request the server returns an error.
There is the example of correct request

```
POST https://host-name.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary;

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="image.png"

< C:/path/image.png
--boundary
```

So i don't understand where is my kotlin method incorrect

**UPDATE**
The 1st variant of method was

```
    suspend fun uploadPhoto(userId: String, bitmapPhoto: BitmapPhoto) {
        kotlin.runCatching {
            val response: HttpResponse = httpClient.submitFormWithBinaryData(
                url = BASE_URL.plus("$userId/${bitmapPhoto.name}"),
                formData = formData {
                    append("file", bitmapPhoto.bitmap.toByteArray(),
                        Headers.build {
                            append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "image/png")
                            append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${bitmapPhoto.name}")
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
}
```

But it wasn't work so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the following headers:

```
append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary")
append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "form-data; name=file; filename=${bitmapPhoto.name}")
```

The `Content-Type` header should have a MIME type of the contents of your file  (`bitmapPhoto`), not a type of the request body (Ktor adds it automatically), e.g. `image/png`. The `Content-Disposition` header should have only `filename=${bitmapPhoto.name}` value for your case because Ktor adds `form-data; name=file;` automatically. So your code should look like this:

```
append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "image/png")
append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${bitmapPhoto.name}")
```

For more information, please refer to the [Ktor documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/request.html#upload_file).

Comment: updated the post, the 1st variant of method i've done with documentation and it looked like your, but unfortinatly it wasn't work so

Comment: Sorry, my fault, the error was in incorrect bitmap compress format